# Two concurrent INSERT ON CONFLICT UPDATE in parallel transactions

Tags: postgresql, upsert

A table contains no record with id=1 initially.

What will be a result after 2 transactions:

```
(1) -------------B+++++++++++++++++++++++C------------------------->
(2) --------------------B+++++++++++++++++++++++C------------------>
```

The first transaction contains UPSERT for a row with id=1

```
INSERT INTO some_table (id, amount) VALUES (1, 10)
ON CONFLICT DO
  UPDATE some_table SET amount=amount+10 WHERE id=1;
```

The second transaction contains a similar one:

```
INSERT INTO some_table (id, amount) VALUES (1, 20)
ON CONFLICT DO
  UPDATE some_table SET amount=amount+20 WHERE id=1;
```

What will be a result?

And as a follow up question, how it will work in this case?

```
(1) -------------B+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++C------------->
(2) --------------------B+++++++++++++++++++++++C------------------>
```

Answer (score 1):

The result is always the same: 30 will be added to `amount`. There is no race condition.

The reason is that the row locks taken by the update serialize the `UPDATE` operations, so the later update can only start when the transaction with the earlier update is committed, and the blocked transaction will see the committed result of the other transaction.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
And to make sure, ON CONFLICT takes care of the duplicate inserts event if they happen in different transactions, am I right?

Comment: Yes. `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT` is by design safe from race conditions.